# Smarty2.6.14+PHP7.1で、Smartyタグ内が無視されてしまう

Tags: php, smarty

Smartyを初めて触ります。

既存システムSmarty2.6.14+PHP4系からの移行に伴い、一部Smartyを利用しているページの改修を行っております。
幾つか不具合が生じていたのでテンプレートhtmlとキャッシュファイルを見比べた所、
テンプレート内部に記述された
・{literal}～{/literal}
・{ldelim}～{ldelim}
に囲われた箇所がキャッシュ内ではすっぽり抜けておりました。

中にはphp文が書かれた物もあったので{php}～{/php}で囲ってみましたが、
状況変わらずキャッシュでは抜け落ちてしまいます。

上記現象の解決策もしくは、テンプレート内で他にPHP文を扱う方法があれば教えていただければ幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 2.6.14だとPHP7.1に適用しているような情報がありませんが、Smartyを最新化はできませんか？https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/Smarty2/ChangeLog

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。やはり現状のSmartyだと厳しそうですね。
Smartyの最新化を検討してみようと思います。